# Tomcat consuming more Memory after Application Data is added .

Tags: tomcat, java, database, cpu-usage, memory-usage

A Tomcat Server suddenly shows an increment of 2 GB memory consumption after adding more data into the Application or Application Oracle Database. What I mean is that after restart Tomcat is normal but after a few hours it shows approx. 2000MB of Memory space . There are 4 Servers and the numbers are close in all the four . Before the data adjoined it was behaving appropriate . Please some one could specify whether this more data in Database which is causing the problem or something else needs to be looked into ??

Parallelly the CPU wait cycles have increased during this time frame .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best course of action would be to profile the Java application running under Apache Tomcat. This will give you better insight and direction on how to solve the issue if there is one.

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028824/profiling-tomcat-application-with-visualvm#39077348

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-jvm

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-performance

Comment: Hey Guys both of your answer ...are good and almost correct . I do not see any body else attending this answer ....thanks for ur effort .

Answer (score 2):

That's a expected behaviour for any database server. More data equals more caching and more processing time for every request.
What I mean it will use all available memory to improve performance.

If you want to change this behaviour you can limit the memory usage check [here](https://crunchify.com/how-to-change-jvm-heap-setting-xms-xmx-of-tomcat/).

**However be aware limiting memory usage probably will degrade the overall performance.**